# how to update a row of a datable that contains a foreign key field error:javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsf, primefaces, foreign-key-relationship

i have a method that returns a List in dao like this. 
I had to return an object because i have a join query.

```
public List<Object> getAllBudgets(Integer id) {
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getSession();
        try
        {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("select r.libelleRubrique, b.creditOuvert, b.creditReporte from Rubrique r, Budgetisation b where r.idRubrique = b.rubrique and b.id.annee =:annee");
            q.setParameter("annee", id);
            listeBudgets = q.list();
            return listeBudgets;
        }
        catch(HibernateException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

i can see the data in the datatable, but i have a problem when it comes to update and delete.
when i want to delete a row, this is the error that i get

```
12-Jun-2014 00:45:46.081 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-10] com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute Cannot convert [Ljava.lang.Object;@2033b6 of type class [Ljava.lang.Object; to class net.vo.Budgetisation
 javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert [Ljava.lang.Object;@2033b6 of type class [Ljava.lang.Object; to class net.vo.Budgetisation
    at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:481)
    at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.SetPropertyActionListenerHandler$SetPropertyListener.processAction(SetPropertyActionListenerHandler.java:209)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

12-Jun-2014 00:45:46.093 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-10] com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert [Ljava.lang.Object;@2033b6 of type class [Ljava.lang.Object; to class net.vo.Budgetisation
    at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:481)
    at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.SetPropertyActionListenerHandler$SetPropertyListener.processAction(SetPropertyActionListenerHandler.java:209)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

budget.xhtml

```
   <h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
       <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
       <h:outputText value="Annee : " style="font-size: 18px" />
       <p:selectOneMenu value="#{anneeBean.annee}"  >
       <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="--Séléctionner une année--" />
       <f:selectItems value="#{anneeBean.listeAnnees}" var="annee" 
                      itemValue="#{annee}" itemLabel="#{annee}" />
      <f:ajax listener="#{anneeBean.submit()}" render="display" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
       </h:panelGrid>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <p:dataTable id="display" var="listeBudgets" value="#{budgetisationBean.listeBudgets}" editable="true" style="margin-bottom:10px">
        <f:facet name="header">
           Budgetisation
        </f:facet>

       <p:column headerText="Libelle rubrique">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeBudgets[0]}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{listeBudgets[0]}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Crédit ouvert">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeBudgets[1]}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{listeBudgets[1]}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Crédit reporté ">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeBudgets[2]}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{listeBudgets[2]}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>
<p:column style="width:32px" headerText="Modifier">
    <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" action="#{budgetisationBean.update()}" process="@this" update="" oncomplete="budgetDialog.show()">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{budgetisationBean.budget}" value="#{listeBudgets}" />
    </p:commandLink>
       </p:column>
           <p:column style="width:32px" headerText="Supprimer">
    <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" action="#{organismedecreditBean.delete()}" process="@this" update=":form:display">
     <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{budgetisationBean.budget}" value="#{listeBudgets}" />
    </p:commandLink>
       </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
     <p:dialog header="Modification du budget" widgetVar="budgetDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
        <p:outputPanel id="budgetDetail" style="text-align:center;">
            <p:panelGrid  columns="2" rendered="#{ empty budgetisationBean.budget}" columnClasses="label,value">
              <h:outputText value="Rubrique : " />
    <p:selectOneMenu>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{budgetisationBean.budget.id.idRubrique}" itemLabel="#{budgetisationBean.budget.id.idRubrique}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

      <br></br>
                                    <h:outputText value="Crédit ouvert: " />
                                    <p:inputText value="#{budgetisationBean.budget.creditOuvert}"/>
<br></br>
                                    <h:outputText value="Crédit reporté: " />
                                    <p:inputText value="#{budgetisationBean.budget.creditReporte}"/>
<br></br>

                <p:commandButton value="Valider" update="display" icon="ui-icon-search" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />

            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
   </h:body>
```

BudgetisationBean.java

```
package controller;

@Component
@Scope("view")
public class BudgetisationBean implements java.io.Serializable{

    @Autowired
    private BudgetisationMetier budgetisationMetier;
    @Autowired
    private RubriqueMetier rubriqueMetier;
    private List<Object> listeBudgets;
    private List<Annee> listeAnnees;
    private List<Object> listeRubriques;
    private Budgetisation budget;
    private BudgetisationId id;
    private Rubrique rubrique;
    private Annee annee;
    private Double creditOuvert;
    private Double modification;
    private Double creditReporte;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        listeAnnees = budgetisationMetier.getListeAnnee();
        listeRubriques = budgetisationMetier.getAllRubriquesNonBudgets();
    }

    public List<Object> getListeRubriques() {
        return listeRubriques;
    }

    public void setListeRubriques(List<Object> listeRubriques) {
        this.listeRubriques = listeRubriques;
    }

    public RubriqueMetier getRubriqueMetier() {
        return rubriqueMetier;
    }

    public void setRubriqueMetier(RubriqueMetier rubriqueMetier) {
        this.rubriqueMetier = rubriqueMetier;
    }


    public List<Annee> getListeAnnees() {
        return listeAnnees;
    }

    public void setListeAnnees(List<Annee> listeAnnees) {
        this.listeAnnees = listeAnnees;
    }

     public List<Object> getListeBudgets() {
        int a = AnneeBean.submit();
         System.out.println(a);
        listeBudgets = budgetisationMetier.getAllBudgets(a);
        return listeBudgets;
    }

    public void update()
    {
        Budgetisation budget = budgetisationMetier.getBudget(this.id);
    budgetisationMetier.update(budget);
    }
    public void delete()
    {   
        BudgetisationId bu = new BudgetisationId(getBudget().getRubrique().getIdRubrique(),getBudget().getAnnee().getAnnee());
        Budgetisation b = budgetisationMetier.getBudget(bu);
        budgetisationMetier.delete(getBudget().getId());
        listeBudgets.remove(budget);
        budget = null;
    }
    public BudgetisationMetier getBudgetisationMetier() {
        return budgetisationMetier;
    }

    public void setBudgetisationMetier(BudgetisationMetier budgetisationMetier) {
        this.budgetisationMetier = budgetisationMetier;
    }

    public BudgetisationId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(BudgetisationId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Rubrique getRubrique() {
        return rubrique;
    }

    public void setRubrique(Rubrique rubrique) {
        this.rubrique = rubrique;
    }

    public Annee getAnnee() {
        return annee;
    }

    public void setAnnee(Annee annee) {
        this.annee = annee;
    }

    public Double getCreditOuvert() {
        return creditOuvert;
    }

    public void setCreditOuvert(Double creditOuvert) {
        this.creditOuvert = creditOuvert;
    }

    public Double getModification() {
        return modification;
    }

    public void setModification(Double modification) {
        this.modification = modification;
    }

    public Double getCreditReporte() {
        return creditReporte;
    }

    public void setCreditReporte(Double creditReporte) {
        this.creditReporte = creditReporte;
    }

}
```

this is a screenshot of my page, so that you could understand what i'm talking about
[image]

Comment: You need a [converter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-custom010.htm)

Comment: can you explain what's the converter and how i would use it in my case.I'm new to JSF and i don't really understand all the specifities @kolossus